# How to find Dictionary Key(s) from Value in a large nested dictionary of variable depth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say that I have a large dictionary full of nested values such as this:

```
large_dic ={
...
"key":{"sub-key1" :{"sub-key2": "Test"}},
"0key":{"0sub-key1": "0Test"},
"1key":{"1sub-key1":{"1sub-key2":{"1sub-key3":"1Test"}}}
...
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to get for example from the final value:

```
"1Test"
```

the key(s) to access it, such as in this case:

```
large_dic["1key"]["1sub-key1"]["1sub-key2"]["1sub-key3"]
```

Thanks for the support.

Edit to add more infos: The dictionary trees I'm talking about are linear(YAML files converted into a python dictionary structure), there is never more than one key, the ending leaf values may not be unique.

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Should you do this? Probably not if you need to do so regularly. It would be more efficient to use a different data structure, or at the very least create a different dictionary with different key-value pairs. Are your leaf values unique? Could a dictionary at one of the deeper levels have more than one key?

Comment: Also, you probably didn't mean to ask "is this possible", since the answer to that is usually a single word: yes/no. I would suggest you should [edit] the question to include your attempt (as a [mre]) and/or thought process, and ask a _specific_ question about where you got stuck. See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953).

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/39188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve this. You might want to look up "prefix tree traversal" (or "trie traversal").

A simple recursive solution with poor memory efficiency could look like this:

```py
def find_trie_leaf_path(trie: dict, leaf_value, trie_path: list[str] = []):
    for key, value in trie.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from find_trie_leaf_path(value, leaf_value, trie_path + [key])
        elif value == leaf_value:
            yield trie_path + [key]

large_dic = {
    "key": {"sub-key1": {"sub-key2": "Test"}},
    "0key": {"0sub-key1": "0Test"},
    "1key": {"1sub-key1": {"1sub-key2": {"1sub-key3": "Test"}}},
}


first_match = next(find_trie_leaf_path(large_dic, "Test"))
all_matches = list(find_trie_leaf_path(large_dic, "Test"))
```

This should work even if your trie is very wide. If it is very high, I'd rather use an iterative algorithm.

I want to point out, though, that prefix trees are usually used the other way round. If you find yourself needing this search a lot, you should consider a different data structure.

Comment: Could you explain what you did here: "trie_path: list[str] = []" or point me in the right direction to understand?

Comment: Sure! That's a  keyword argument with a default value (`[]`). The `: list[str]` part is a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since OP is looking for hierarchical keys instead
I made this class :

```py
class PointingSlice:
    def __init__(self, obj, *slices) -> None:
        self.obj = obj
        self.slices = slices

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.obj)}{''.join(map(self._repr_slice, self.slices))}"

    def _repr_slice(self, sliced: slice):
        sqbrackets = "[{}]"
        if not isinstance(sliced, slice):
            return sqbrackets.format(repr(sliced))
        items = [sliced.start, sliced.stop, sliced.step]
        fn = lambda x: str() if x is None else str(x)
        return sqbrackets.format(":".join(map(fn, items)))

    def resolve(self):
        obj = self.obj
        for sliced in self.slices:
            obj = obj.__getitem__(sliced)
        return obj
```

and this function for instantiation :

```py
def find_longest(mapping, key):
    keys = [key]
    value = mapping[key]
    while isinstance(value, dict):
        ((k, value),) = value.items()
        keys.append(k)
    return PointingSlice(mapping, *keys)
```

Example use:

```py
print(find_longest(large_dic, "1key"))
# output:
# {'key': {'sub-key1': {'sub-key2': 'Test'}}, '0key': {'0sub-key1': '0Test'}, '1key': {'1sub-key1': {'1sub-key2': {'1sub-key3': '1Test'}}}}['1key']['1sub-key1']['1sub-key2']['1sub-key3']
# do note that it is the same thing as large_dic['1key']['1sub-key1']['1sub-key2']['1sub-key3']
print(find_longest(large_dic, "1key").resolve()) # 1Test
```

So I made some changes and now it supports additional repr options matching your exact use case :

```py
class PointingSlice:
    def __init__(self, obj, *slices, object_name=None) -> None:
        self.obj = obj
        self.slices = slices
        self.object_name = object_name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.object_name or str(self.obj)}{''.join(map(self._repr_slice, self.slices))}"

    def _repr_slice(self, sliced: slice):
        sqbrackets = "[{}]"
        if not isinstance(sliced, slice):
            return sqbrackets.format(repr(sliced))
        items = [sliced.start, sliced.stop, sliced.step]
        fn = lambda x: str() if x is None else str(x)
        return sqbrackets.format(":".join(map(fn, items)))

    def resolve(self):
        obj = self.obj
        for sliced in self.slices:
            obj = obj.__getitem__(sliced)
        return obj


large_dic = {
    "key": {"sub-key1": {"sub-key2": "Test"}},
    "0key": {"0sub-key1": "0Test"},
    "1key": {"1sub-key1": {"1sub-key2": {"1sub-key3": "1Test"}}},
}


def find_longest(mapping, key):
    keys = [key]
    value = mapping[key]
    while isinstance(value, dict):
        ((k, value),) = value.items()
        keys.append(k)
    return PointingSlice(mapping, *keys)


f = find_longest(large_dic, "1key")
f.object_name = "large_dic"  # for representational purposes, it works without this
print(f)  # large_dic['1key']['1sub-key1']['1sub-key2']['1sub-key3']
print(f.resolve())  # 1Test
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asking, starting point would be `1Test" and not `1key`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally possible. Here's the function to get the deeply nested value:

```py
def get_final_value(mapping, key):
    value = mapping[key]
    while isinstance(value, dict):
        (value,) = value.values()
    return value
```

Example use:

```py
>>> get_final_value(large_dic, "key")  
'Test'
>>> get_final_value(large_dic, "0key") 
'0Test'
>>> get_final_value(large_dic, "1key") 
'1Test'
>>>
```

Comment: My question is not about the deeply nested value but about getting the keys to access that value, such as for example getting "large_dic["1key"]["1sub-key1"]["1sub-key2"]["1sub-key3"]" from the final value "1Test".

Answer (score -1):

Can the parent keys be deduced from your final value in any way or is the tree structure rather random? If latter is the case then you'll probably just end up searching your tree until you find your `value`, what path search algorithm you choose for that again depends on the tree structure you have. As already asked in the comments, does each node only have one other node or is it binary or can it have many child nodes?

Comment: The dictionary trees I'm talking about are linear(YAML files converted into a python dictionary structure), there is never more than one key/node, the ending leaf values may not be unique.

Comment: But if the ending leaf value is not unique, what would be the expected output?

Comment: A list of lists containing the keys to pass through to reach the leaf value. See danzel's code.